# C++ call function by string, compare performance with PHP, how to optimize code in C++?

Tags: php, c++

I am going to write a program that can let us to call function with string in C++. However, I wrote a program with same behavior in PHP, but PHP only took 4 seconds and finish executing, however, C++ took 27~28 seconds to finish.
I wonder why PHP much faster than C++, and how to optimize the C++ code.

P.S. I am using Qt API, so the class name with prefix 'Q' such as QHash, QObject are classes from Qt.

Here are my code:

## C++ code:

class header definition:

```
// function_dispatcher.h

#ifndef FUNCTIONDISPATCHER_H
#define FUNCTIONDISPATCHER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QHash>
#include <functional>

class FunctionDispatcher : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FunctionDispatcher(QObject* parent = 0);
    int functionDispatcher(QString functionName, int dataA, int dataB);
    int function1(int a, int b);
    int function2(int a, int b);
    int function3(int a, int b);
    int function4(int a, int b);
    int function5(int a, int b);
    int function6(int a, int b);
    int function7(int a, int b);
    int function8(int a, int b);
    int function9(int a, int b);
    int function10(int a, int b);
    void functionTable();
private:
    QHash<QString, std::function<int(int, int)>> m_functionsTable;
};

#endif // FUNCTIONDISPATCHER_H
```

class body definition:

```
#include "functiondispatcher.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <functional>

#define ADD_FUNCTION(_functionName, _function) m_functionsTable.insert(_functionName, std::bind(_function, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));

FunctionDispatcher::FunctionDispatcher(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
        functionTable();
}

int FunctionDispatcher::functionDispatcher(QString functionName, int dataA, int dataB)
{
    std::function<int(int, int)> func = m_functionsTable.value(functionName);
    int result = 0;
    try {
            result = func(dataA, dataB);
    }
    catch(const std::bad_function_call& e) {
            qDebug() << e.what();
    }

    return result;
}

int FunctionDispatcher::function1(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int FunctionDispatcher::function2(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}

int FunctionDispatcher::function3(int a, int b)
{
    return a / b;
}

int FunctionDispatcher::function4(int a, int b)
{
    return (a+12) * b;
}

int FunctionDispatcher::function5(int a, int b)
{
    return (a+1) * b;
}

int FunctionDispatcher::function6(int a, int b)
{
    return (a+2221) * b;
}

int FunctionDispatcher::function7(int a, int b)
{
    return (a+31) * b;
}

int FunctionDispatcher::function8(int a, int b)
{
    return (a+11) * b;
}

int FunctionDispatcher::function9(int a, int b)
{
    return (a+141) * b;
}

int FunctionDispatcher::function10(int a, int b)
{
    return (a+12) * b;
}

void FunctionDispatcher::functionTable()
{
    ADD_FUNCTION("function1", &FunctionDispatcher::function1);
    ADD_FUNCTION("function2", &FunctionDispatcher::function2);
    ADD_FUNCTION("function3", &FunctionDispatcher::function3);
    ADD_FUNCTION("function4", &FunctionDispatcher::function4);
    ADD_FUNCTION("function5", &FunctionDispatcher::function5);
    ADD_FUNCTION("function6", &FunctionDispatcher::function6);
    ADD_FUNCTION("function7", &FunctionDispatcher::function7);
    ADD_FUNCTION("function8", &FunctionDispatcher::function8);
    ADD_FUNCTION("function9", &FunctionDispatcher::function9);
    ADD_FUNCTION("function10", &FunctionDispatcher::function10);
}
```

and main function here:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "functiondispatcher.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    time_t t1 = time(NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i ++) {
        FunctionDispatcher *f = new FunctionDispatcher();
        f->functionDispatcher("function1", i, i + 1);
        f->functionDispatcher("function2", i, i + 1);
        f->functionDispatcher("function3", i, i + 1);
        f->functionDispatcher("function4", i, i + 1);
        f->functionDispatcher("function5", i, i + 1);
        f->functionDispatcher("function6", i, i + 1);
        f->functionDispatcher("function7", i, i + 1);
        f->functionDispatcher("function8", i, i + 1);
        f->functionDispatcher("function9", i, i + 1);
        f->functionDispatcher("function10", i, i + 1);
        delete f;
    }
    time_t t2 = time(NULL);

    qDebug() << t2 - t1;
}
```

## PHP code:

```
<?php
class Dispatcher
{
        public function function1($a, $b)
        {
                return $a + $b;
        }
        public function function2($a, $b)
        {
                return $a * $b;
        }
        public function function3($a, $b)
        {
                return $a / $b;
        }
        public function function4($a, $b)
        {
                return ($a + 1) * ($b + 1);
        }
        public function function5($a, $b)
        {
                return $a / $b;
        }
        public function function6($a, $b)
        {
                return $a / $b;
        }
        public function function7($a, $b)
        {
                return $a / $b;
        }
        public function function8($a, $b)
        {
                return $a / $b;
        }
        public function function9($a, $b)
        {
                return $a / $b;
        }
        public function function10($a, $b)
        {
                return $a / $b;
        }
}
$time1 = time();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10000000; $i ++)
{
        $function = new Dispatcher();
        $function->{"function1"}($i, $i + 1);
        $function->{"function2"}($i, $i + 1);
        $function->{"function3"}($i, $i + 1);
        $function->{"function4"}($i, $i + 1);
        $function->{"function5"}($i, $i + 1);
        $function->{"function6"}($i, $i + 1);
        $function->{"function7"}($i, $i + 1);
        $function->{"function8"}($i, $i + 1);
        $function->{"function9"}($i, $i + 1);
        $function->{"function10"}($i, $i + 1);
}
$time2 = time();
echo $time2 - $time1;
```

Comment: Unrelated: Save yourself the headaches of dynamic allocation. replace `FunctionDispatcher *f = new FunctionDispatcher();` with `FunctionDispatcher f;`, replace all of the `f->` with `f.`, and remove the `delete f;` Might even be a bit faster because dynamic allocation can be slow.

Comment: Are you timing a debug build or a release build? Debug builds are often slower by orders of magnitude because they're compiled to make debugging easier.

Comment: There is no point to rebuilding `m_functionsTable` every time. Make it `static` and build it once.

Comment: `sts::bind` is slow. Also, enable optimization, avoid `std::function` in favor of pointer to member function, and about dynamic allocation.

Comment: Also, `QString` has a high chance of being slower because it does not have short string optimization.

Comment: @user4581301 I will modify `f->` to `f.`, it went faster, thank you. I am using -O2 flag when compiling with release build. Furthermore, I am going to handle HTTP request, and I will construct a new object when a new request come, so rebuilding `m_functionsTable` every time is necessary. I am going to use precompiling code to improve performance here, building a function table at compile time.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Tell us the improved execution times, please ;)

Comment: @user2328447 The improved code is attached below:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DO NOT use `std::function`. Use function pointer instead.

`std::function` is a wrapper of ANY `Callable` target including functions, functor, lambda expression etc. It is so heavy and you don't need it in your situation .

Then make sure you turn on the `-O2` (or even `-O3`) option when compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should use const references at some places.

```
int FunctionDispatcher::functionDispatcher(const QString& functionName, int dataA, int dataB)
{
    const std::function<int(int, int)>& func = m_functionsTable.value(functionName);
    int result = 0;
    try {
            result = func(dataA, dataB);
    }
    catch(const std::bad_function_call& e) {
            qDebug() << e.what();
    }

    return result;
}
```

might perhaps already increase performance a lot.
Call by value is usually much slower in C++ than to do it with references.
Also, your local func variable doesn't need to be a copy.

Answer (score 1):

My final solution is:

I split `Dispatcher` from Controller and build `functionsTable` only one time, and I use function pointer point to call function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <map>

class Controller
{
public:
        int function1(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
        int function2(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
        int function3(int a, int b) {return a * b;}
        int function4(int a, int b) {return a + 50 + b/2;}
        int function5(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
        int function6(int a, int b) {return a / 2 + b;}
        int function7(int a, int b) {return a + b * 19;}
        int function8(int a, int b) {return a + b * 20;}
        int function9(int a, int b) {return a + b + 100;}
        int function10(int a, int b) {return a / b;}
};

typedef int (Controller::*function)(int a, int b);

class Dispatcher
{
public:
        Dispatcher()
        {
                m_functionsTable.insert(std::pair<std::string, function>("function1", &Controller::function1));
                m_functionsTable.insert(std::pair<std::string, function>("function2", &Controller::function2));
                m_functionsTable.insert(std::pair<std::string, function>("function3", &Controller::function3));
                m_functionsTable.insert(std::pair<std::string, function>("function4", &Controller::function4));
                m_functionsTable.insert(std::pair<std::string, function>("function5", &Controller::function5));
                m_functionsTable.insert(std::pair<std::string, function>("function6", &Controller::function6));
                m_functionsTable.insert(std::pair<std::string, function>("function7", &Controller::function7));
                m_functionsTable.insert(std::pair<std::string, function>("function8", &Controller::function8));
                m_functionsTable.insert(std::pair<std::string, function>("function9", &Controller::function9));
                m_functionsTable.insert(std::pair<std::string, function>("function10", &Controller::function10));
        }
        int FunctionDispatcher(std::string functionName, int a, int b) {
                Controller c;
                function f = m_functionsTable.find(functionName)->second;
                return (c.*(function)f)(a, b);
        }
private:
        std::map<std::string, function> m_functionsTable;
};


int main()
{

        time_t t1 = time(NULL);

        Dispatcher d;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i ++) {
                d.FunctionDispatcher("function1", i, i + 1);
                d.FunctionDispatcher("function2", i, i + 1);
                d.FunctionDispatcher("function3", i, i + 1);
                d.FunctionDispatcher("function4", i, i + 1);
                d.FunctionDispatcher("function5", i, i + 1);
                d.FunctionDispatcher("function6", i, i + 1);
                d.FunctionDispatcher("function7", i, i + 1);
                d.FunctionDispatcher("function8", i, i + 1);
                d.FunctionDispatcher("function9", i, i + 1);
                d.FunctionDispatcher("function10", i, i + 1);

        }

        time_t t2 = time(NULL);
        std::cout << t2 - t1 << std::endl;
}
```

This solution took 3 seconds to run the program.

If I increase the loop from 10 million times to 100 million times, it only took 21 second, but PHP took 41 seconds.

My execution environment:

- E3-1230 v5
- 16GB DDR4
- 256GB SATA3 SSD

I upload the code to "ideone", and it shown that the program only took 5 seconds.
link here: https://ideone.com/7DUXYG

Comment: By the way, I use this solution on Qt API, and 10 million times loop took 13~14 seconds to finish to program, and took 133 seconds to finish the program when 100 million times loop.

Comment: C++ is the winner, that's the way it should be :)
But I noticed that the creation of your "Dispatcher" is now outside of the loop, but you said you explicitly wanted it to be created it each loop? This is of course better for the performance, but unless you didn't change your PHP code too this might be a pretty heavy comparison bias.

Comment: I create `Dispatcher` in the loop, it is because I put `dispatcher()` function in the `Foo` class, you can see the code in my question. I didn't come up with this solution that I can split dispatcher from the class and use pointer to member function of the class, after instanciating object, use pointer to point the function I want.

Comment: I want to handle HTTP request, each request has each controller to handle request, at first I came up with the solution in question, I build the function table that point to "this" function, and the bottle neck is rebuilding function table every time.
And in this solution, I only need to build function table one time, and I can implement the behavior that each request has each controller.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker, please forgive my not fluent English.

Comment: Ah ic. Seems to be the much better way. Indeed the function table creation is very heavy, I tried it here and placing it in the loop body raised the execution time from 4s to 17s. So this seems to be the major slowdown in your original program. And your English is very good :)

Comment: Aaand btw, changing the `functionName` parameter of `FunctionDispatcher()` to `const functionName&` (like I suggested) saves another 10% of execution time (measured with `clock_t t1 = clock();`, which has a millisecond resolution). But this of course might depend on your compiler (I use Visual Studio)

Comment: @user2328447 you're right, execution decreased from 21 seconds to 19 seconds. That's awesome!